# How to show the title of toolbar in floating state in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I tried the function `addToolBar()` like this:
.h file

```
QToolBar* toolbar;
```

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent):QMainWindow(parent)
{
  toolbar= new QToolBar("Normal Tool");
  toolbar->setFloatable(true);
  toolbar->setFixedSize(200,50);
}
```

When dragged the toolbar out of the mainWindow,I can't see the title.How can I show the title?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] of what you have tried, and show it to us. Also please include the programming language you use when you [edit] your question.

Comment: Have you tried calling [`toolbar->setWinowTitle("Normal Tool")`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop)?

Comment: I tried, it didn't work.